# Check if 'T' inherits or implements a class/interface

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to test if T inherits/implements a class/interface?

```
private void MyGenericClass<T> ()
{
    if(T ... inherits or implements some class/interface
}
```

Comment: this appears to work...if(typeof(TestClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))), could someone confirm my suspicions? thanks!

Comment: I'm absolutly sure that this answer is duplicated many times!

Comment: Felix K Even if this answer has been duplicated many times, it also helps a lot of guys many time ;) ... like me five minutes ago :)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

There is a Method called [Type.IsAssignableFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

To check if `T` inherits/implements `Employee`:

```
typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

If you are targeting .NET Core, the method has moved to TypeInfo:

```
typeof(Employee).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T).Ge‌​tTypeInfo())
```

Note that if you want to constrain your type `T` to implement some interface or inherit from some class, you should go for @snajahi's answer, which uses compile-time checks for that and genereally resembles a better approach to this problem.

Comment: you should update your answer with an example, 

e.g. typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IMyInterface))

Comment: Not done nikeee; the old answer is still there. :) I took a couple of secondes to figure out what's wrong. In anyways, +1, nice feature again of the .net framework.

Comment: In fact, the way you mention is the way I had it some time ago. I corrected this one. See previous comments. `T inherits U` actually translates to `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(U))`.

Comment: @Chalky is actually right. `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(U))` actually translates to `U inherits from T`. See my explanation below.

Comment: Fixed. Now it's the way it was as I answered two years ago. Lol.

Comment: While this almost works, there is an issue where if `T` is constrained to some other type `TOther`, then when executed, `typeof(T)` will actually evaluate to `typeof(TOther)` and not whatever type `T` you had actually passed, and in that case, `typeof(SomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` will fail (assuming `TOther` does not also implement `SomeInterface`), even though your concrete type did implement `SomeInterface`.

Comment: For those that are targeting core, you should add the changed syntax.  The function has moved to TypeInfo.

`typeof(Employee).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));`

Comment: In .net core `IsAssignableFrom` of `TypeInfo` class only accepts TypeInfo as it's only argument, so the sample should be the following:
`typeof(Employee).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T).GetTypeInfo())`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but in .Net 5 IsAssignableFrom is still part of the Type class.

Answer (score 40):

You can use constraints on the class.

```
MyClass<T> where T : Employee
```

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 21):

If you want to check during compilation: Error if if `T` *does NOT* implement the desired interface/class, you can use the following constraint

```
public void MyRestrictedMethod<T>() where T : MyInterface1, MyInterface2, MySuperClass
{
    //Code of my method here, clean without any check for type constraints.
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

The correct syntax is

```
typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

## Documentation

> **Return Value:** `true` if `c` and the current `Type` represent the same type, or if the current `Type` is in the inheritance hierarchy of `c`, or if the current `Type` is an `interface` that `c` implements, or if `c` is a generic type parameter and the current `Type` represents one of the constraints of `c`, or if `c` represents a value type and the current `Type` represents `Nullable<c>` (`Nullable(Of c)` in Visual Basic). `false` if none of these conditions are `true`, or if `c` is `null`.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx)

## Explanation

If `Employee IsAssignableFrom T` then `T` inherits from `Employee`.

The usage

```
typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Employee))
```

returns `true` **only** when either

1. `T` and `Employee` represent the same type; or,
2. `Employee` inherits from `T`.

This may be intended usage in *some* case, but for the original question (and the more common usage), to determine when `T` inherits or implements some `class`/`interface`, use:

```
typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

Answer (score 13):

What everyone really means is:

```
typeof(BaseType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DerivedType)) // => true
```

because you can literally *assign from* an instance of a `DerivedType` to an instance of a `BaseType`:

```
DerivedType childInstance = new DerivedType();
BaseType parentInstance = childInstance; // okay, assigning base from derived
childInstance = (DerivedType) parentInstance; // not okay, assigning derived from base
```

when

```
public class BaseType {}
public class DerivedType : BaseType {}
```

---

And some concrete examples if you're having trouble wrapping your head around it:

*(via LinqPad, hence the `HorizontalRun` and `Dump`)*

```
void Main()
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718364/check-if-t-inherits-or-implements-a-class-interface

    var b1 = new BaseClass1();

    var c1 = new ChildClass1();
    var c2 = new ChildClass2();
    var nb = new nobase();

    Util.HorizontalRun(
        "baseclass->baseclass,child1->baseclass,baseclass->child1,child2->baseclass,baseclass->child2,nobase->baseclass,baseclass->nobase",
        b1.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseClass1)),
        c1.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseClass1)),
        b1.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ChildClass1)),
        c2.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseClass1)),
        b1.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ChildClass2)),
        nb.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseClass1)),
        b1.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(nobase))
        ).Dump("Results");

    var results = new List<string>();
    string test;

    test = "c1 = b1";
    try {
        c1 = (ChildClass1) b1;
        results.Add(test);
    } catch { results.Add("FAIL: " + test); }

    test = "b1 = c1";
    try {
        b1 = c1;
        results.Add(test);
    } catch { results.Add("FAIL: " + test); }

    test = "c2 = b1";
    try {
        c2 = (ChildClass2) b1;
        results.Add(test);
    } catch { results.Add("FAIL: " + test); }

    test = "b1 = c2";
    try {
        b1 = c2;
        results.Add(test);
    } catch { results.Add("FAIL: " + test); }

    results.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class exts {
    public static bool IsAssignableFrom<T>(this T entity, Type baseType) {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(baseType);
    }
}


class BaseClass1 {
    public int id;
}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass1 {
    public string name;
}

class ChildClass2 : ChildClass1 {
    public string descr;
}

class nobase {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string descr;
}
```

### Results

> baseclass->baseclass
>
> True
>
> child1->baseclass
>
> False
>
> baseclass->child1
>
> True
>
> child2->baseclass
>
> False
>
> baseclass->child2
>
> True
>
> nobase->baseclass
>
> False
>
> baseclass->nobase
>
> False

and

> - FAIL: c1 = b1
> - b1 = c1
> - FAIL: c2 = b1
> - b1 = c2

Answer (score 2):

I believe syntax is: `typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));`

Comment: This is the intended syntax. +1

Answer (score 0):

Although IsAssignableFrom is the best way as others have stated, if you only need to check if a class inherits from another, `typeof(T).BaseType == typeof(SomeClass)` does the job too.

Comment: That works unless `SomeClass` is not directly derived from `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate ways to tell if an object `o` inherits a class or implements an interface is to use the `is` and `as` operators.

If you want to only know if an object inherits a class or implements an interface, the `is` operator will return a boolean result:

```
bool isCompatibleType = (o is BaseType || o is IInterface);
```

If you want to use the inherited class or implemented interface after your test, the `as` operator will perform a safe cast, returning a reference to the inherited class or the implemented interface if compatible or null if not compatible:

```
BaseType b = o as BaseType; // Null if d does not inherit from BaseType.

IInterface i = o as IInterface; // Null if d does not implement IInterface.
```

If you have only the type `T`, then use @nikeee's answer.