# How to find out type of generic parameter T if it was passed as an Interface?

Tags: c#, generics, types

for some reasons, which are too boring to explain here, I need to know the type of a passed generic parameter. I found a way, how this can be achieved in case that T is an instantiable class:

```html
[...]
T dummy = default(T);
if (dummmy is MyClassA)
{
   //do something => this works fine
}
else if (dummy is MyClassB)
{
   //do something else...
}
[...]
```

But if I pass not an instantiable Class, but an Interface as T, dummy will be null and therefore the if-clause "if (dummy is..." will cause an exception. OK, I could set constraints to make sure that only instantiable classes can be passed as T. But in my case I need the possibility to pass instantiable classes as well as Interfaces to this method.

Can anybody help me? How can I find out the type of T in case it is an Interface?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if 'T' inherits or implements a class/interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718364/check-if-t-inherits-or-implements-a-class-interface)

Comment: Nit: `default(T)` for an "instantiable Class" *returns null*, not a new instance. To create a new instance one would need to refine T, eg, `where T: new` and use `new T()`. In that case the compiler will simply forbid using a non-concrete type at the generic parameter usage site.. thus T could not even be a bare interface.

Comment: default(T) of any 'class' is always null, by definition, and the 'is'-operator is not testing equality, it's testing compatiblity. If your MyClassB is derived vom MyClassA, then your second branch would be unreachable code, sind "is MyClassA" is also valid for any instance of MyClassB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Type` that represents `T`, and use the [`IsInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinterface?view=netframework-4.8) property:

```
Type type = typeof(T);
if (type.IsInterface) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to know which interface is passed, just use `==` to compare the `Type` objects, e.g.

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(IConvertible))
```